how to fix "clear current selection before next search" ubuntu 24.04?
I upgraded to ubuntu 24.04, then I have been getting issues with the "find" feature of libreoffice (any of the suite's app). When I have tried to search for a "word or string pattern" then I get a message stating "clear current selection before next search", then when the libreoffice is minimized, icons on my desk folder appears to be "highlighted as selected" (Though I havent selected them). Another behavior is that when working with a workplace or file's windows, if I click in such windows, that clicking brings up another workplace. Some times this behavior is solved by hitting the space/blank key.Some others, it doesnt work at all. Some other times, I got a message about having to install nautilus-sushi for icons. And last behavior is that when an application's workplace-windows is in a second plane, it cannot be brought up to 1st plane by clicking on it
All this problems happen only when workplace-windows are maximized, when they are running minimized, everything goes well and smoothly (with the exception of the find feature)
I have been reading and I cannot find how to fix this behavior.
Might it be something related with genome 46 vs 47.10
Regards
emphasized text

I cannot reproduce this. Provide exact steps on what you do and how you search so others can attempt to reproduce the problem. Use "Edit" to update your question.
